# Creating number patterns in java

Tags: java, design-patterns

I need to  create these patterns in java according to however many lines the user enters:

```
1
12
123
1234
12345

54321
4321
321
21
1


     1
    21
   321
  4321
 54321
```

I can do the first two  but I cannot do the third.
Here is the code for the second:

```
public static void displayPatternII (int lines) {

    for (int i = 1; i <= lines; i++){
        for (int j = lines + 1 - i; j > 0; j--)
            System.out.print (j + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: _I can do the first two but I cannot do the first two_ ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 public static void displayPatternIII (int lines) {

    for (int i = 1; i <= lines; i++){
      System.out.print(" ");
        for (int j = lines; j > 0; j--)
            System.out.print (j > i ? " " : j);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you breifly explain how you got this?

Comment: The first loop is the same because it's the same number of rows. And the second print line is the same for the same reason. The middle loop prints something out, whether it be a space or a number, every time so you loop through the number of columns. Then you figure if I haven't hit the number of the row I'm on I print a space otherwise a number...Brief I think not but oh well.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at [Formatter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) Instead of manually trying to pad the spaces. I also agree that your message is a bit confusing...

Answer (score 0):

I will not give you an answer, but I will tell you what has to be done.

Lets take

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
```

From 1 to a particular number (from the user or whatever) (lets call this max)
    you print all the numbers from 1 to the current index

```
54321
4321
321
21
1
```

Same as the one above, but you loop backwards

```
     1
    21
   321
  4321
 54321
```

From 1 to max
   print n+1 spaces where n is the difference between the max and the current index

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like homework, I will give you a solution I doubt you can submit to give you some ideas. ;)

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    displayPatternIII(5);
}

public static void displayPatternIII(int lines) {
    int cols = lines + 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < cols * lines; i++) {
        int x = i % cols;
        int y = i / cols;
        if (x == lines + 1)
            System.out.println();
        else if (x + y < lines)
            System.out.print(' ');
        else
            System.out.print(cols - x - 1);
    }
}
```

prints

```
     1
    21
   321
  4321
 54321
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Series
{
    public static void main()
    {
        int i,j,k;
        for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
        {
            for(j=5;j>=i;j--)
            System.out.print(" ");
            for(k=i;k>=1;k--)
            System.out.print(k);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: add some comments to your answer to be more helful.

Answer (score 0):

Click here for better  understanding
[Java Number Pattern](https://youtu.be/K0N2zWtH3uk)

```java
public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        //declare the size
        //change the size
        int size = 5;
        
        //use two loops
        //outer loop to set the number of iterations i.e size
        for(int i=1; i<=size; i++){
            //use inner loop with a limit
            for(int j=1; j<=i; j++){
                System.out.print(""+j);
            }
            //use print statement with println to print in next line
            System.out.println("");
        }
        //run the program
       
    }
}
```