# core java printing a butterfly structure

Tags: java

```
package mypack;

public class Loop {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    for(int i=0;i<=8;i++){
        for(int j=1;j<=i+1;j++){
            System.out.print(j);
        }
        System.out.println();

    }
    for(int i=8;i>=1;i--){
        for(int j=1;j<=i;j++){
            System.out.print(j);
        }
        System.out.println();

    }

        }

    }
```

output::

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
123456
1234567
12345678
123456789
12345678
1234567
123456
12345
1234
123
12
1
```

i want the mirror image of it on right side.
can someone help me with this.

Comment: Place a mirror on your screen with the reflective surface facing left, such that the side of the mirror lies parallel to the line of `1`s and the face of the mirror is perpendicular to the screen. Bam! You have the mirror image (literally!) of that on the other side.

Comment: More seriously, what have you tried? "Here's what I want, can someone help" is generally considered to be too broad on Stack Overflow.

Comment: hint hint.. you need to print the left and right sides in the same iteration.

Comment: I am just a beginner and i have started practicing java from yesterday , i am just trying to print some patterns.But i was stuck here.If you have no intention to help no need to comment satirically.

Comment: I'm happy to help if I see some effort on your part. If you're stuck, take a step away from the computer, pull out a pencil and some paper, and figure out how *you*, as a human would do it. What would you do? Can you break those actions down into steps? Can you turn those steps into instructions you can give to someone else? Now can you turn those instructions into pseudocode? Into Java code? Basically imagine you're giving instructions to someone who takes things too literally, because that's *exactly* what you're doing. Edward has given a starting point. Perhaps go from there?

Comment: This link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22572617/number-patterns-using-loops-in-java

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to count the `number of spaces` before you add the reflection of the numbers to form a butterfly effect in the console, using the `String.format`

**sample:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int j;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
        for ( j = 1; j <= i + 1; j++) {
            System.out.print(j);
        }
        System.out.print(String.format("%"+((10 - j)*2 != 0 ? (10 - j)*2 : "")+"s", ""));

        for ( j = i + 1; j >= 1; j--) {
            System.out.print(j);
        }
        System.out.println();

    }
    for (int i = 8; i >= 1; i--) {
        for ( j = 1; j <= i ; j++) {
            System.out.print(j);
        }

        System.out.print(String.format("%"+((10 - j)*2 != 0 ? (10 - j)*2 : "")+"s", ""));

        for ( j = i; j >= 1; j--) {
            System.out.print(j);
        }
        System.out.println();

    }

}
```

**results:**

```
1                1
12              21
123            321
1234          4321
12345        54321
123456      654321
1234567    7654321
12345678  87654321
123456789987654321
12345678  87654321
1234567    7654321
123456      654321
12345        54321
1234          4321
123            321
12              21
1                1
```

Answer (score 1):

one easy way is to do:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int limit = 10;
    String left = "%-9s";
    String right = "%9s";
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        for (int j = 1; j < i + 1; j++) {
            b.append(j);
        }
        System.out.println(String.format(left, b.toString())
                + String.format(right, b.reverse().toString()));
    }
    // skipping the redundant line from last syso in above loop
    for (int i = limit - 2; i > 0; i--) {
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        for (int j = 1; j < i + 1; j++) {
            b.append(j);
        }
        System.out.println(String.format(left, b.toString())
                + String.format(right, b.reverse().toString()));
    }
}
```

idea is to print the sequence (left aligned) and then print its reverse(right aligned) in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

package mypack;

public class Loop {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    for(int i=0;i<=6;i++){
        for(int j=1  ;j<=i+1;j++ ){
            System.out.print(j);    
            }
        System.out.print("\t");
        for (int j=0;j<6-i;j++)
            System.out.print(" ");

                             for (int k=1;k<=i+1;k++)
                              System.out.print(k);

        System.out.println();

    }
    for(int i=6;i>=0;i--){
        for(int j=1;j<=i+1;j++){
            System.out.print(j);
        }
        System.out.print("\t");
        for (int j=0;j<6-i;j++)
            System.out.print(" ");

                             for (int k=1;k<=i+1;k++)
                              System.out.print(k);

        System.out.println();

    }

        }

    }
```

got it by myself,thank you all..