# Formatting a list of numbers using for loops in python

Tags: python, loops, nested-loops

So I've got a homework assignment I'm having some trouble with.

We're supposed to use nested for loops to display a set of numbers in a variety of different ways. I need 3 out of 4 of the following patterns, and I only know how to make 1.

Pattern A

```
1 

1  2

1  2  3

1  2  3  4

1  2  3  4  5
```

Pattern B

```
1  2  3  4  5

1  2  3  4

1  2  3

1  2

1
```

Pattern C

```
            1

         2  1

      3  2  1

    4  3  2  1

5  4  3  2  1
```

Pattern D

```
1  2  3  4  5

    1  2  3  4

        1  2  3

            1  2

                1
```

(I don't know why C and D won't display right, but you should have the idea)

I've got the following code to make Pattern A:

```
for x in range(5):
    for y in range(1, x + 2):
        print(y, end = '\r')
    print()
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number Patterns using loops in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22572617/number-patterns-using-loops-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a padding by using `" " * y`

Another way is to iterate over all 25 spots and choose to print either a space or the number at each location

```
for y in range(1, 6):
    for x in range(1, 6):
        print(" " if x > y else x, end=" ")
    print()
```

notice what happens if you substitute `x > (6 - y)` into the comparison

also try reversing the ranges. eg.

```
 for y in reversed(range(1, 6)):
```

Comment: Thank you VERY much. I got it all figured out and was able to submit in time.

Answer (score 0):

What do you see changing for part C and D? There's the numbers that change along with the initial space between the first number, right? That implies you need to keep track of # of spaces in your loop. As for A and B, if you can piece together the algorithm for 1, you can do the other. Hint: what's the initial starting point for each pattern and how does it change?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Python 3's `print()` function, you can unpack `range` objects with the `*` operator and leverage `print()`'s convenient `sep` and `end` arguments:

Pattern A:

```
for i in range(5):
    print(*range(1, i+2), sep='  ', end='\n\n')
```

Pattern B:

```
for i in range(5, 0, -1):
    print(*range(1, i+1), sep='  ', end='\n\n')
```

Pattern C:

```
for i in range(5):
    print('   '*(4-i), end='')
    print(*range(i+1, 0, -1), sep='  ', end='\n\n')
```

Pattern D:

```
for i in range(5, 0, -1):
    print('   '*(5-i), end='')
    print(*range(1, i+1), sep='  ', end='\n\n')
```